# How to replace n occurrences of a char with n-m occurrences of the same char

Tags: vim

All is in the title.
I can give an example: Assume I want to replace 75 times `c` with 30 times `c`

I know this is something like `:%s#c\{75}#???#g`, but I don't find the ??? part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This substitution should do the trick:

```
:%s/\(c\)\{75}/\=repeat(submatch(1),30)/g
```

The pattern is enclosed in a group for use with `submatch()` which is then repeated 30 times with `repeat()`.

Answer (score 1):

one way to go is using macro.

```
qq/c\{75}<cr>45xq
```

then

```
x@q
```

`x` is how many times you want to do the replacement.

if you don't know the times, you can use recursive macro: `qq/c\{75}<cr>45x@qq` then `@q`

Answer (score 1):

How about instead replacing (n-m)+m characters, with (n-m) characters?

```
:%s;\(c\{45}\)c\{30};\1;g
```